# UILabel with custom class not showing on device, works in simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uilabel, subclass

I have a bunch of custom UILabels (same custom class used in different places) all set in storyboard, what the class does is set two attributes - line height and kerning.
Strangely the labels work fine on the simulator but they just do not show up when testing on device (iPhone 6s)!
I have tried giving a background colour to the label and that shows, so I'm guessing it has something to do with the actual text not rendering...

I'm totally confused and really appreciate any help.

Thanks

Edit 1 (Code)

```
- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self)
    {
        [self setTheAttributes];
    }

    return self;
}

- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self)
    {
        [self setTheAttributes];
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)prepareForInterfaceBuilder
{
    [self setTheAttributes];
}

- (void)setTheAttributes
{
    NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithAttributedString:self.attributedText];


    CGFloat multiplier = _lineSpacing / self.font.lineHeight;

    NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [NSMutableParagraphStyle new];
    paragraphStyle.lineHeightMultiple = multiplier;


    [attributedString addAttribute:NSKernAttributeName
                             value:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:_kerning]
                             range:NSMakeRange(0, self.text.length)];

    [attributedString addAttribute:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName
                             value:paragraphStyle
                             range:NSMakeRange(0, self.text.length)];


    [self setAttributedText:attributedString];
}
```

Edit 2 ----

Using the View Hierarchy Debugger, I checked the label and it shows the text in the inspector, so I am sure that it is there it is most likely an issue of rendering - possibly because of using the attributes on the label.

Comment: Please post the relevant code.

Comment: You can check in the capture user interface mode thing wether the labels are actually visible on the screen or not. If there are rectangular shapes where your label should be and don't have text inside them, then its because of text not rendering otherwise there is a problem with your constraints if the rectangular box itself isn't visible.

Comment: @caxix Code is now added, this is the UILabel Subclass

Comment: @IrLearn I have already done that and also tried with setting the background colour on the label and the label is there just the text.

Comment: Have you tried to set some dummy text to the label? Just to check if the label can actually show some text.

Comment: @dasdom I tried that now, still the same!